# ASP:NET - GridVIEW - DropDownList selectedvalue

Tags: asp.net

I am new at this forum though I have passed many years looking for answers into it. Now,I will like your help to solve an issue. I am following this [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-DropDownList-with-Selected-Value-in-EditItemTemplate-of-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx) to make my own DropDown List in my Grid and works fine until this line:

```
ddlCities.Items.FindByValue(country).Selected = True
```

here,I have got error:

> **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

but my code is right in affected fields:

this is relevant code in Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow AndAlso grdLinea.EditIndex = e.Row.RowIndex; 

        Dim ddlCities As DropDownList = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddlFacturarA"), DropDownList)


        ' Create the command with the sproc name and add the parameter required'
        ddlCities.DataSource = GetData("select UPPER(DSCA_ZONA)as Zona from tb_personal  where dsca_Zona <> 'NULL'group by dsca_zona order by dsca_zona")
        ddlCities.DataTextField = "Zona"
        ddlCities.DataValueField = "Zona"
        ddlCities.DataBind()

        'Add Default Item in the DropDownList
        'ddlCountries.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Please select"))

        Dim country As String = Trim(CType(e.Row.FindControl("lblFacturarA"), Label).Text)
        ddlCities.Items.FindByValue(country).Selected = True

    End If
End Sub
```

and this is affected code in design mode:

```
    <EditItemTemplate >
    <asp:label ID="lblFacturarA" Value ='<%# Eval("facturar_a")%>' Visible ="false" runat="server" />

                <asp:DropDownList 
                    ID="ddlFacturarA"  
                    CssClass="txt"   
                    runat="server" 

                    AutoPostBack="True" ValidationGroup="rfNewLineEmpty">
                </asp:DropDownList>



                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
                    ID="rfNewLineFacturarA" 
                    runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="Obligatorio" 
                    ValidationGroup="rfNewLine" 
                    SetFocusOnError="True" 
                    ControlToValidate="ddlFacturarA">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

I know I am new at ASP.NET and maybe I am loosing something by the way, but I have been round this code for two days and don't see light.

can you tell me something about reason for this error?

please,let me know if you need more detailed information to solve this.

thanks in advance

Comment: are you able to found Lable?

Comment: Yes, eve i've made it visible. If I comment this line of code, dropdownlist loads fine. Issue comes when try to make retrive field from database as selected value of combo

Comment: You mean to say country string have some value that is in Label lblFacturarA , right?

Comment: As per your link, do you have a Label with same name in Item Template also?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that error is on line `ddlCities.Items.FindByValue(country).Selected = True` and `country` item is in dropdown list, I suggest you double check that is there white space or upper/lower case difference in dropdown list item and country variable.

because [`FindByValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbyvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) finds exact item and it is case sensitive.

You should try changin query to  `RTRIM(LTRIM(UPPER(DSCA_ZONA))) as Zona` 

and 
`ddlCities.Items.FindByValue(country.ToUpper()).Selected = True`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for delay as I been outside, i think i've solved in this way

**Dim country As String = Trim(CType(e.Row.FindControl("lblFacturarA"), Label).Text)
ddlCities.Items.Insert(0, country)**

and now it's working fine, Do you think this is a valid way?

many thanks!!!